# PHP file show download link after renamed upload

Tags: php, file-upload

Hello my PHP script i have set up uploads files via a html form.

I'm hoping to show a download link / open file link after the upload but the problem is a section of the PHP script I'm using renames the file on upload

```
//Create full filename including path
    if ($random_name_enable = true) {
        // Generate random filename
        $tmp = str_replace(array('.', ' '), array('', ''), microtime());

        if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
            $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
        }
        $newname = $tmp . '.' . $ext;
    } else {
        $newname = $name . '.' . $ext;
    }
enter code here
```

This results in me not knowing how show a download link with the renamed uploaded file via the php solution below

The upload webpage / site is located at https://beta.filez.ml

as you can see if you try to upload a basic image is does not show the renamed download link, I need to figure out a way to get the PHP script to show a link after the rename of the upload shown below.

The Full PHP file is here for anyone interested in picking it apart

```
https://gist.github.com/burnsyboo/b9a9512807fc031dc9a7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to just above the $newname variable add global $newname; then at the top of the page i did $newname "";

Then where the success message was displayed i did this

```
$message = "<style>.php-success { color: darkgreen; font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px; }</style><p class='php-success'>File successfully Uploaded<br><br><a href=\"https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/uploads/" . $newname . "\">Click here to open</a></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Ajax? when upload is done, echo new file name that you generated, ajax takes that name and then append anchor with href with file name that you got from php and add download attribute to anchor so it downloads file when pressed

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: i'm not sure how to do this

the problem is me pulling the name of the file after it being renamed by php

I tried using the variable $newname but that gave me an unused error

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the picture of error or text of the exact error

Comment: hey Marko its not an error its a question how to achieve somthing

Comment: Where did you try to echo $newname? you can only use that variable in the php where you grab uploaded file, as I said, showing the download link after submitting can be done with Ajax if you want it on same page, or you can insert file path and save it do DB and then after upload redirect your user to download page